# about Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I've got some trouble with the sieve of eratosthenes.
So i've got the mathmatics calculations for the sieve from a book called "Schaum's outlines" but i think the book has programmed to code wrong...
**This is the code from the book:**

```
public class Sieve
{
    final static int P = 800;
    static boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[count];

Sieve();
{
    for (int i = 2; i<P; i++)
    {
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i<P/2; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime[i])
        {
            for (int j = 2*i; j<P; j += i)
            {
                isPrime[j] = false;
            }
        }   
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Sieve();
    print();
}

static void print()  {
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        if (isPrime[i]) System.out.println(i + " ");
        else if (i%90==0) System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
}}
```

So yeah i used the code and made some slight changes due to the fact that "Sieve()" isn't recognized. **Here below is my code:**

```
public class Primenumbers
{
    final static int count = 1000;
    static boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[count];

    public static sieve(int count, boolean isPrime);
    {
        for (int i = 2; i<count; i++)
        {
            isPrime[i] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i<count/2; i++)
        {
            if (isPrime[i])
            {
                for (int j = 2*i; j<count; j += i)
                {
                    isPrime[j] = false;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            if (isPrime[i])
            {
                System.out.println(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So... what am i doing wrong?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: what's the issue? Compiler error? Runtime Exception? Wrong output? Anything else?

Comment: Compiler error about the public static sieve
error: invalid method declaration; return type required

Comment: So isn't the compiler message clear enough? You need to give return type to your `sieve()` method.

Comment: By removing the method and replace it by static it worked but why do you only use static without a method name or type of method it is... can you explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what am i doing wrong?

You have defined `sieve()` but you never call it. You need to call it before printing:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    sieve(); // <<== Here
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime[i])
        {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason it worked in the book was that the initialization has been done in the constructor. Your modified code moved the initialization into a static function, but it fails to call that initialization.

You also need to remove parameters from the declaration of `sieve`, because it already has access to `isPrime` and `count`.

An alternative is to remove the `sieve` method altogether, replacing it with a static initializer. Instead of

```
public static sieve() 
{
    // Code to initialize isPrime
}
```

write

```
static
{
    // Code to initialize isPrime
}
```

This change makes `sieve()` method a static initializer, which is always called before anything else in your class gets to execute.

Comment: Ok i added it into the main method but it still gives the error while compiling on: `public static sieve(int count, boolean isPrime);`

Comment: @SteelDevil By the way, you need to remove semicolons in method amd constructor declarations - for example, I bet you there's no semicolon after `Sieve();` in the book.

Comment: Alright that did it! but why do you only use static what does it do as a method? can you explain it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! + for you sir or ma'am or bot i don't know lol :)